# local HREF="" tag is not linking one page to another

Tags: html, css

I am writing a local page in HTML/CSS and I am stuck with my anchor tag communication. I can't seem to link the page I am on now to another one saved in the same folder.

This is the case for any of my reference tags and the files associated with those files.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Exceptions</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="panel panel-default" align="center">
  <div class="panel-body"><h2>Exception Training</h2></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Daily Exceptions</h3>
  <p>Please choose which excpetion you are going to be trying to fix today</p>
  <p>The Exception choiices are going to be on your left in the blue drop down menu</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Please Choose...
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily Exceptions\Flow_not_gross.html">Time Frame Less Than/Equal to 3 weeks</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily Exceptions\Time_Frame_less_3.html">Time Frame Less Than/Equal to 3 weeks</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily Exceptions\initial_flow_not_net.html">Initial Flow Not Net Need</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily Exceptions\Flow_not_gross.html">Flow Not Gross Need</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily Exceptions\store_inv_greater_100.html">Store Inv >= 100</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="1"  href="C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily Exceptions\exceptions_net_inv_100.html">Net Inv >= 100</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily Exceptions\Deal_Alloc_greater_100.html">Deal Alloc >= 100</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I reference it, it gives me this very generic error:

> Page not found

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: Add an code example to show what you have done. So others can help you

Comment: You need to post an example of the code.

Comment: You might want to learn to use [relative links](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Comment: don't use a full path.

Comment: place the html files on your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode `space` character in path with `%20` and append `file:///` before path

```
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="file:///C:\Users\af\Desktop\JavaScript\test\Daily%20Exceptions\Time_Frame_less_3.html">Time Frame Less Than/Equal to 3 weeks</a></li>
```

Although, as you mentioned, your files are in same directory, then you don't need to use full path, you can use relative path as

```
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="Time_Frame_less_3.html">Time Frame Less Than/Equal to 3 weeks</a></li>
```